# Relationship between Fatou's lemma and St.Petersbourg paradox.

Tags: probability-theory

This an example from a book, that I'm having some difficulties understanding.

We're playing the roulette. Let the probability of winning $p<1/2$.

Our bet at $n$-th turn is $H_n=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
      0,& \text{ if there was a winning in previous bets} \\
    2^{n-1},&\text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.$
(I start with $H_1=1$, and then double the bet if I've lost)

Let $S_n=\sum^n_{i=1}H_iD_i$, where $D_i=1$ if you win the $i$-th bet, $D_i=-1$ if you lose the bet. Then we know that $P(S_n=1-2^n)=(1-p)^n$ and $P(S_n=1)=1-(1-p)^n$

Also $S= 
\begin{cases}{}
    -\infty,& \ -1=D_1=D_2=..., \\
    1,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} 
$

According to the author, we have $S_n\rightarrow^{n\rightarrow \infty} S$ a.s. ( I think this is because $P(S_n=1)\rightarrow 1$), but $\lim_{n->\infty}\int S_n dP<\int S dP=1$. The author states that by Fatou's lemma, this inequality is only possible since there is no integrable minorant for $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Why is this?I'm not getting the exact relation with the lemma...

To prove this the author defines $\tilde S = \inf \left\{ S_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} $, then $P(\tilde S=1-2^{n-1})=P(D_1=D_2=...=D_{n-1}=-1, \ D_n=1)=p(1-p)^{n-1}$, hence $\int \tilde S \ dP = -\infty$.

Also, what's the relationship between the S tilde and the lemma? Because $\tilde S \leq \inf_{m\geq n}S_n$,implying $\displaystyle \tilde S \leq \liminf_{n->\infty}S_n$ when we would like equality...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were an integrable minorant, say $M$, for the $S_n$, then Fatou's lemma, applied to the non-negative $S_n - M$ would yield

\begin{align}
\int S\,dP &= \int M\,dP + \int (S -M)\,dP \\
&= \int M\,dP + \int \liminf_{n\to\infty} (S_n - M)\,dP \\
&\leqslant \int M\,dP + \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int (S_n - M)\,dP \\
&= \liminf_{n\to\infty} \Biggl(\int M\,dP + \int (S_n - M)\,dP\Biggr) \\
&= \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int S_n\,dP.
\end{align}

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the answer.  I've just edited my question because I forgot to ask something more. What's the relation between the lemma and the S tilde?

Comment: and the integrable minorants

Comment: $\tilde{S}$ is the largest minorant of the $S_n$. So for every minorant $M$, we have $\int M\,dP \leqslant \int \tilde{S}\,dP = -\infty$, showing that there is no integrable minorant. I think that's all there is to $\tilde{S}$, the author proves explicitly that a minorant can't be integrable. Does the author use $\tilde{S}$ for anything else?

Comment: Daniel, when you say it's the largest minorant of S_n, do you mean in the sense of $\sup \inf S_n$? I thought of that, but in the event where up until bet K we lose, and at K+1 we win, we have the $\inf \{S_n : n \in N\}=1-2^K$, but $\sup \inf  S_m = 1$, because $\inf_{m\geq K+1} S_m=1$

Comment: No, that just means that $M$ is a minorant if and only if $M \leqslant \tilde{S}$. Maybe the author uses it for something else, but so far, it looks like it's pretty much just an aside remark. There's no need to introduce $\tilde{S}$ if the author only wants to show that $S_n \to S$ almost surely, and yet $\lim \int S_n\,dP < \int S\,dP$.